# Gradle: BuildServiceParameters object is not serializable

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose I have a simple Gradle build service:

```
abstract class MyService : BuildService<MyService.Parameters> {
    abstract class Parameters @Inject constructor(private val objects: ObjectFactory) : BuildServiceParameters {
        val item: NamedDomainObjectSet<MyClass> = objects.namedDomainObjectSet(MyClass::class.java)
    }
}
```

Registering an instance of `MyService` goes through smoothly, but when it comes time to actually create the instance via `Provider.get()`, I get an error like so:

```
Could not isolate value from MyService$Parameters_Decorated@foobar of type MyService.Parameters
org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.IsolationException
...
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.snapshot.ValueSnapshottingException: Could not serialize value of type MyService.Parameters
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: MyService$Parameters_Decorated
```

Suppose that `MyClass` is a Gradle managed object (or otherwise created from an `ObjectFactory` instance). Is it because of anything related to `item` that this error occurs?

The original use case here is to have the build service "synchronize" with data taken from an extension object created by the plugin that registered the `MyService` instance. Hence, `item` has a `Rule` that populates the list from the extension object - perhaps this is a contributing factor to the error?

Comment: Can you share the definition of `MyClass`, or a similar class that causes the same problem?

Comment: @aSemy The weird thing is that if I comment out `item` and leave `Parameters` with nothing, the same error persists. For the record, in my use case `MyClass` is an interface whose known implementations are Gradle managed (abstract) classes.